# Can Ethereum Stack Exchange have a Documentation area like Stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I noticed the very interesting - but still beta - [Documetation area](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) on Stackoverflow. Can we enable the same here? I think it will be very helpful for a topic like Ethereum. Moreover, we already have many Q&A that are really more *well written Documentation* then Q&A.